# Firefox plug-in that downloads a complete webpage?

Tags: html, firefox, download

I recall using a Firefox plug-in that saves a web-page to disk, including all dependencies, such as images, CSS, Javascript, etc.

Just can't recall the exact name of it.

I think it was called "snapshot" or something, but I've been Googling for half an hour and still can't find it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: More of a superuser question?

Comment: Maybe it fits in both places - it can be considered linked to programming as a tool for web development (store to analyze offline).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use ScrapBook

http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/feature1.php

Download link : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427

add on : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8186

[image]
<sub>(source: [vis.ne.jp](http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/screen/Detail.png))</sub>

Comment: Scrapbook is really great, I've used it quite a bit. It also suffers from lack of updates sometimes, so it's not always reliable - but it's the best I've found, so no complaints

Answer (score 6):

In my Firefox the menu item

```
File->Save Page As->Web Page, Complete
```

saves all javascript and images and css.  No plugin required.

Comment: This option ignores CSS included with `<style>@import url("style.css");</style>`

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126309

Comment: I wish! This feature regularly misses assets.

Comment: Even though this is old, Firefox's own save web page complete also doesn't save img's defined in css styles.

Answer (score 1):

Though ScrapBook can do the job, I think the following plugin is better. It saves the web page into a single file, which is more manageable. And it claims a "faithful save".

http://maf.mozdev.org/

Comment: The webpage I was trying to save had its DOM modified by clicking some javascript links. This plugin was able to capture the newly rendered DOM. Good!

Comment: Mozilla Archive Format seems to have been discontinued in maybe 2018.

Comment: @Andrew Try SingleFile extension for the chrome. It saves the whole page as static HTML as-is.  Also I have a tool with similar function specific for SO: https://github.com/smwikipedia/StackExchangeArchiver

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly it was ... "Save Complete" (no longer supported)

https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/save-complete-4723/

Wish it was .......