# Saving and restoring an html page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I need to write an extension that does something like:

- Saving the current HTML in a local file
- Open the local file

The problem is that by opening `file://.../page.html` the relative urls (e.g `<img src="/img.jpg"/>`) don't work anymore.

I tried changing all the relative urls to absolute urls before savining the page, by it's quite impossible to change all of them correctly.

Anyone can think of some workaround?

Comment: You mean, like the built-in ["Save as web page, complete" feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061324/785541)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `base` tag to the document's head:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html