# Export a SiteCore Page

Tags: sitecore

I am looking to export an entire sitecore page. Ideally, upon exporting the links would move from relative to absolutely, but that's not necessary. I want to download the html, css, images, everything from one of my pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to download one page only, you should be able to just use **Save** option in your browser. Most of the modern browsers supports all of your requirements. **Sitecore** web page is like any other html page.

If you want to download the whole site, you can try to use http://www.httrack.com/, **wget** or [Firefox plugin as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061311/firefox-plug-in-that-downloads-a-complete-webpage/2061336#2061336).

If none of those are enough, try to search for `save entire site with images and css` in your favourite search engine - there are plenty of other possibilites.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up doing this but then hit another issue along this road. See my new question for better details on the problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896118/facebook-iframe-app-will-not-display

Thank you for your help, it got me one step further in this process.

Answer (score 1):

If I only have to locally save a page hosted in our Sitecore (really doesn't matter what's hosting it) I use wget.

This seems to work quite well:

```
wget.exe -E -H -k -K -p --no-check-certificate <your url>
```

You can change the parameters to recursively spider the whole site, if you do so make sure to check with your security department to not set of any alarms.