# Facebook iFrame App Will Not Display

Tags: facebook, iframe, ssl, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe

I have searched through many pages on SO and cannot seem to find the answer I am looking for.

I have a website (created via CMS SiteCore) that I want to display via an iFrame on a Facebook page. however, due to some SSL issue (I still do not fully understand the issue, but I know it is related to SSL), Facebook will not display it.

I thought a possible solution would be dwonlaoding all of the content (HTML, CSS, Images, etc) and just recreate it in an HTML editor app for Facebook. Wrongo. The app does not let me upload images, and when I link to the images on my server, it hits this SSL issue again and will not display images.

I just want this page to display when clicking on the app. Here is the page:

http://www.pplweb.com/home/social/facebook/pplcareers/v2/careers_fb_v2_hj.ashx

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To display your app inside the Facebook iframe, you must have a valid SSL certificate for the domain you are hosting your app on. When I try to call your given URL via HTTPS however my browser warns me that the server name does not match the server name in the certificate.

Comment: I usually only code and never really work on the server end, I just throw my stuff up there. Could you please explain how I can go about fixing this issue? Thank you so much.

Comment: Ask your server admin to get you a valid SSL certificate for the domain.

Comment: Your site is located at www.pplweb.com but your SSL cert is for www.pplelectric.com. There may be other issues too with the iFrame and Facebook, but you've got to fix this first or nothing will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you require a SSL Certificate can get them as low as $17 in Geotrust if need be or a dearer one in hostgator or godaddy as well and they will install it for if have them as a host... once attached to domain should show the site or webpage in FB within Iframes... Also as the previous poster need to have domains the same one using the iframes in FB as that is where you want it right displayed...
Hope helps
Rick Ling